# Networking (subnet)

Tags: ip, subnet

I am new to networking and I am trying to learn about it.
I can't make my on subnets.

My questions are:

What does "there are possible 32 hosts" mean?

Do hosts address and ip addresses change from time to time?

Comment: This is not a good question for this site. Answering that requires a primer on networking. I suggest that you start with reading this post: http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work

Answer (score 0):

> What does "there are possible 32 hosts" mean?

It means you are dealing with a /27 network, one with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.224, capable of having 32 hosts. For example, 192.168.10.64/27 has 32 possible hosts (devices with IP addresses), ranging from 192.168.10.64 through 192.168.10.95, although in most cases it is really 30 hosts since the first is used as the network address (192.168.10.64) and the last as the broadcast address (192.168.10.95), which leaves 192.168.10.65-94 as usable IP addresses. Also remember that for traffic to leave the subnet, you need a gateway which also consumes one of those IP addresses.

> Do hosts address and ip addresses change from time to time?

That is entirely dependent on your network setup, if you use DHCP then it is entirely possible, if you statically assign the whole network then no they will not change.

I would suggest doing some basic research into IP networking and subnetting, there are tons of resources online, including the one @Hennes mentioned in his comment, or [Microsoft's Knowledge Base](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/164015), Cisco's article on [IP Addressing and Subnetting for New Users](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/routing-information-protocol-rip/13788-3.html), or any number of articles that Google can lead you to.